# Highlight parents of list but not all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have created a `<ul>` element and what I am trying to do is to highlight the list elements from a certain child and all the way up. However, because of the nested children, when I highlight a parent also all its children are highlighted (while I want to highlight only the text of the parents).

https://jsfiddle.net/zcfvuh6h/3/

In this example, I should get the nodes Four12, Four1 and Four highlighted.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: So where's the code with what you've tried?

Comment: Do you have the code that is troubling you that you could post, or give a link to a live demo, such as a JSFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zcfvuh6h/

Comment: more clear version: https://jsfiddle.net/zcfvuh6h/3/

Comment: Good luck getting the help you need on this; From the activity on this so far I can see that you're going to need some kind of luck to find someone you're going to actually be willing to let help you.

Comment: I'm very close. Give me a few more minutes and I will have a solution for you

Comment: @mhodges You've been working on this for the last 40 minutes and you haven't gotten so much as an upvote. If you can't even get a reply why bother? I was willing to look past the downvote and negative comment but when it's this obvious that the OP isn't even trying, maybe it would be best to just let the OP figure it out.

Comment: @JonathanGray In the OP's defense, my attempt at guessing what the OP was looking for was off-base and didn't solve the issue at hand. I feel obligated to post a correct solution at this point. But yes, I agree, some participation from the OP would be nice..

Comment: The OP was not connected and until now didn't have the privilege of voting. I've been working on it for a couple of days but I'm missing something and cannot think clearly of a solution. Nobody is obliged to help of course, but if you do I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @user2007716 My solution is updated & working as you have requested

Comment: @JonathanGray, as you can see, I've used the website to post only very few questions and I still learn how it works. It was not me who downvoted your post or anyone's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT:

Okay, so after understanding what the actual problem you are trying to solve is, it took a bit of work, but I got a working solution.

[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zcfvuh6h/7/)

**A few things to note**

1. All of your text in your `<li>`need to be in a container of some sort, a `<span>` is fine. You had some in spans and some not, so I put them all in spans for you.

2. This cannot be done with `background-color` on the `<li>` or `<ul>` because it spans multiple lines if it has children. You have to use a [`css pseudo-element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) in order to get the desired effect.

3. The demo I have posted also dynamically sets the background of the element and parents based on which element you click on. **You must click on a list item in order for the backgrounds colors to show up.**

4. Your d3 code that you included is all obsolete at this point. It can be done with 7 toal lines of jQuery.

5. Enjoy!

## HTML

```
...
  <li id="i6"><span class="listItem">Four</span>
    <ul>
      <li id="i7" class="listItem"><span class="listItem">Four1</span>
          <ul>
            <li id="i71" class="listItem"><span class="listItem">Four11</span>
               <ul>
                  <li id="i4111" class="listItem"><span class="listItem">Four111</span></li>
                  <li id="i4112" class="listItem"><span class="listItem">Four112</span></li>
               </ul>
              </li>        
            <li id="i12" class="listItem"><span class="listItem">Four12</span></li>
          </ul>
      <li class="listItem"><span class="listItem">Five</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
...
```

## Javascript

```
$(function () {
  $(".listItem:not(li)").on("click", function () {
    var parentListItem = $(this).parent();
    $("#menu1 .highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    parentListItem.addClass("highlight").parents("li").addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

## CSS

```
.highlight {
  position: relative;
}
.highlight > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.highlight::before {
  content: ' ';
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: The JSFiddle is not working for me. I have tried in IE11, FF 44 as well as Chrome 50, but there is no cyan background visible at all.

Comment: @altocumulus You need to click on an `<li>`. It is not hard-coded like the OP's original example. It dynamically sets the background based on which element you click - I will add that information to my post

Comment: Oh, this is awesome! Thank you very much, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @user2007716 Remember to mark an answer as the accepted answer if it was the solution that you went with to resolve your issue. This helps future users quickly identify working solutions so they, too, can get their problems resolved